# How to image button to SharedPreferences and save it

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Hello guys i have a question. 
I have a button with 2 options like checked and unchecked for girl and i have same for boys. In my fragment i need to select one and save it in SharedPreferences.

i have this for configure buttons:

```
private void setSexButtons() {

    sexButtonBoy.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        sexButtonBoy.setSelected(true);
        sexButtonBoy.setScaleX(1.4f);
        sexButtonBoy.setScaleX(1.4f);
        sexButtonGirl.setSelected(false);
        sexButtonGirl.setScaleY(1.0f);
        sexButtonGirl.setScaleX(1.0f);
        Settings.setSelectedIem(true);

    });

    sexButtonGirl.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        sexButtonBoy.setSelected(false);
        sexButtonGirl.setSelected(true);
        sexButtonGirl.setScaleX(1.4f);
        sexButtonGirl.setScaleX(1.4f);
        sexButtonBoy.setScaleY(1.0f);
        sexButtonBoy.setScaleX(1.0f);
        Settings.setSelectedIem(true);
    });
}
```

and i also have a method to save - but i think i do something bad becouse this not work

```
public static void setSelectedIem(boolean selectedIem) {
    getPreferences().edit()
            .putBoolean(SELECTED_SEX, selectedIem)
            .apply();
}

private static final String SELECTED_SEX = "selectedSex";
```

Please give me any advice how to do this good.

Sorry i miss it here is it:

```
privated SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

and in onCreate

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("me.fast.app", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and here is main method:

```
private static SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
    return ApplicationFast.sharedPreferences;
}
```

Updated with new method

```
public static boolean isSelectedItem(){
        return getPreferences().getBoolean(SELECTED_SEX, false);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your `getPreferences` method?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i edited main post

Comment: now is fully edited

Comment: where is the code for getting the SELECTED_SEX?
should be something like this:
boolean value = getPreferences().getBoolean(SELECTED_SEX, *some default value*)

Comment: U mean that method i updated right now?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is saving a boolean, because for both sexes you are saving "true".

You should do this:

```
private void setSexButtons() {
    //If you want to recover the settings do this:
    sexButtonBoy.setSelected(Settings.isSelected());
    sexButtonGirl.setSelected(!Settings.isSelected());

    sexButtonBoy.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        sexButtonBoy.setSelected(true);
        sexButtonBoy.setScaleX(1.4f);
        sexButtonBoy.setScaleX(1.4f);
        sexButtonGirl.setSelected(false);
        sexButtonGirl.setScaleY(1.0f);
        sexButtonGirl.setScaleX(1.0f);
        Settings.setSelectedIem(true);

    });

    sexButtonGirl.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        sexButtonBoy.setSelected(false);
        sexButtonGirl.setSelected(true);
        sexButtonGirl.setScaleX(1.4f);
        sexButtonGirl.setScaleX(1.4f);
        sexButtonBoy.setScaleY(1.0f);
        sexButtonBoy.setScaleX(1.0f);
        Settings.setSelectedIem(false);
    });

}
```

And then:

```
public static void setSelectedIem(boolean selectedIem) {
   getPreferences().edit()
          .putBoolean(IS_BOY, selectedIem)
          .apply();
}

private static final String IS_BOY = "isboy";
```